# Django: How to increment URL?

Tags: django, url

How to increment the URL?
I have a poll app, a user can vote in a question with "yes" and "no" each time.
I would like to know how to redirect the user to the next question after the user vote for the actual question. Let's say in total I have 10 questions saved in the database.
I don't want to show all 10 questions in the same page.
I've read about making it with ajax and also I did read about passing question id in the url. If anyone can clarify it for me. Thanks!!
I tried this one.

```
 path('question/<int:question_id>', views.QuestionVoteView.as_view(), name='question')
```

And this one.

```
 path('question/', views.QuestionListView.as_view(), name='question')
```

And to vote on the actual question.

```
 url(r'^nope/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', poll_views.nope, name='nope')
 url(r'^yep/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', poll_views.yep, name='yep')
```

Comment: Um... can you describe more? your urls.py and etc. Now your url is `poll/ilst/` => and you want to change to `poll/list/1`,  `poll/list/2`... per ids?

Comment: Exactly. I have edited it with the actual URL code.

Comment: How do you know if user has already voted on a question? your view and Question Model would be great to help you

Comment: That's a problem I have to think yet on how to prevent a user to vote in same questions more than once. I was planning to add a primary key composite in the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just add `<int:question_id>` to your `poll_views` urls.

```
 url(r'^nope/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', poll_views.nope, name='nope')
 url(r'^yep/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', poll_views.yep, name='yep')
```

And in `views`, you can get question id from url (`kwargs`) and can get your question object, add +1 for vote number.

Plus, you don't have to add `user_id` in urls. you can get current authenticated user in template & views by `request.user`. So, your url can be

```
 url(r'^nope/(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', poll_views.nope, name='nope')
 url(r'^yep/(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', poll_views.yep, name='yep')
```

and find current user using `request.user`.

> And I found out that you use both `url()` and `path()`. What django version do you use? If 2.0, you have to use `path()` and if 1.xx use `url()`.

Comment: I see, but I didn't understand where is the url increment for the next question. I'm using Django 2.0.

Comment: I don't understand the word `url increment`. Does it mean `/nope/1/` => `/nope/2/` ? Two urls are different page. If you want to go other url, you just make a tag with the `url`, using `get_absolute_url()`.

Comment: Nope, it's `/question/1/` => `/question/2/`
I got it, I've made the logic in the view to change the value after the vote XD
Thank you, you did help clarify a lot of things!!